# Composer's classmap autoload removing existing maps when new files are added

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm working on a Laravel 5 project and when adding new class files to an existing PHP project, the previously generated classmaps fail to be detected and/or several of the new class files are not detected.

There isn't a global composer.json for the environment, but this is the local package composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
       "classmap": [            
            "database/seeds"
        ]
    }
}
```

`composer dump-autoload` is run with every attempt. This has not helped the issue of the adding the new classes, or even keeping the existing class maps.

I have tested the issue by adding files containing new classes and/or blank files to the project, and in all cases only a subset of the existing classmaps are re-generated, and in the case of the new class files some of the new files are included in generated classmap.

Sample file (existing):
**AccessTypeSeeder.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class AccessTypeSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('site_managements')->insert(
            [
                [
                    'meta_key' => 'access_type',
                    'meta_value' => 'all',
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'updated_at' => Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                ],
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Removing the new files, and re-running `dump-autoload` often restores the existing classmaps, even if the files themselves are blank. Cloning(copy & paste) an existing file like the one above and renaming the class and file name to something unique like **TestSeeder** and **TestSeeder.php**, doesn't make a difference.

The existing classes are not contained in any namespace as seen above, and trying to configure the autoload via **PSR-0**, strangely still generates some of the classmaps (usually 1 or 2) in the `autoload_classmap.php` file, even if no classmap-based autoloading has been defined:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "":["database/seeds"]
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The project is using docker containers and composer (v1+/v2) is applied to the source files via a separate images and containers. It is preferred to get this working with the original classmap-based solution if possible, even though it is less ideal than the preferable PSR-0 or PSR-4 configurations.

I reviewed similar composer autoload issues on SO but the issue causes were not the same and the solutions recommended were not applicable to this is or did not work.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to have been a result of the setup environment which was within a Docker container. Running the composer script outside of the container allowed for the full maps to get created.